# Writing Spark data frame data to kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I need to push the data of dataFrame's column value to kafka and not the column name,  how I will do that if I have data of column like [{"a":"1"}, {"b":"2"}]

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please update the question with input, expected output, what you have tried and create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

In order to write a Dataframe Kafka, you're required to have at least one column named `value`. The column name, literal string "value" is not written to any content of the Kafka record.

Unclear how you got a column named `[{"a":"1"}, {"b":"2"}]`, but you should `alias("value")` it as part of a select query, then you'll have a Kafka record with a null key and value payload of that JSON array. If you want two events of `{"a":"1"}` and `{"b":"2"}`, then you should use an `explode()` function of SparkSQL first